# VS2017 Android Layout designer error

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.3.5). When opening axml files on Xamarin Android sample projects, I kept encountering the following error:

[image: Designer error]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:30)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:187)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:239)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:704)
at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Only the Designer view throws such error. The Code editor works fine. Axml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DataHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="DataHeader"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingStart="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This error happens on multiple Xamarin Android projects. Visual Studio 2017 is newly installed. Please help.

Comment: Can you please try to set the Designer's API level to >= 21?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Looks like it works. Would this mean Xamarin Designer does not work for API level 19 or below ?

Comment: Yeah, seems like so.

Comment: Allright, it works for API level 20 as well. Looks like it only works for API level 20 or above. I can mark your response as the answer..